# PayPal - preauthorized payments from credit card

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

PayPal has an option called Authorize and Capture detailed in their developer section. The information I'm missing is if its possible to charge A&C to a customer who does not have a PayPal account, only a credit/debit card accepted by PayPal.
An random example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
The customer wants to buy tap water. The customer knows I charge $1/gal for the tap water, but doesn't know how much he can fill up. PayPal pre-authorizes his account, blocking $100. The customer tap is then active and the customer fills up 20gal = $20. The end and value of the operation is finished and sent to PayPal API to charge the customer $20 of the withheld $100 and send then $20 to me.
This seems to be possible for customers with an account, but is it also possible for unregistered users?